# How work with Java StringTemplate boolean?

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I wrote the following StringTemplate template lines:

```
<instance.attributes: { attr | <attr.value>}>
<instance.attributes: { attr | <if(attr.value)>skip<else>don't skip<endif> } >
```

in order to write skip if the Object value return by `Instance.getAttributes().getValue()` is a boolean which value is true.

This result in

```
1
skip
```

and

```
0
skip
```

(for now I only have one attribute)

What is the problem and why I don't get ?

```
0
don't skip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [StringTemplate wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet)

> `<if(attribute)>subtemplate <else>subtemplate2 <endif>` if attribute
>   has a value or is a boolean object that evaluates to true, include
>   subtemplate else include subtemplate2. These conditionals may be
>   nested.

I assume that 0 means not `false`, but some value that indicates presence of value and evaluates to true. You need to compute boolean value that evaluates to false **before** pushing it to the template.